# ChefDK 2.0.28 error - "can't modify frozen String"

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chefdk

Simply trying to generate a new skeleton recipe is giving me an error:

chef generate recipe appd_agent

```
================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in 
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-dk-
2.0.28/lib/chef-dk/skeletons/code_generator/recipes/recipe.rb


RuntimeError
------------
can't modify frozen String
```

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this?

Comment: I can't reproduce this locally, can you try and get the underlying stack trace?

Comment: Also probably better to delete this and file a bug report over on the chef-dk project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Chef, it is being tracked in https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/6304.